# Recurrence Relations and Linear-Feedback Shift Registers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I have an exercise for a cryptography/number theory course that I'm trying to work on.

In the exercise, I have a Linear Feedback Shift Register which is working in mod 3 with digits  {0,1,2}.

The LFSR is using a recurrence relation of degree 2, which looks like the following
$$Z_{i+2}=C_0Z_i+C_1Z_{i+1}$$

I also have a part of the keystream $S=...11022...$

I am looking to find $C_0$ & $C_1$ along with the three keystream numbers that follow and precede $S$.

Unfortunately I have no examples to work off so I'm confused on how i'd start even with finding $C_0$ & $C_1$?

The only example I have from class is with the initial part of the keystream.

Comment: IMO this means you can take each digit known in keystream, and get 5 equations - one for each digit. Eg set $i=1$ as first known digit in  keystream. Then $Z_3=C_0Z_1+C_1Z_2=0=C_0+C_1$ etc. Can you then solve the equations for $C_0$ and $C_1$?

Comment: hmmm I don't see how I would get 5 equations for instance if i use the last digit I have 2 I don't have another number to plug into the recurrence relation

Comment: You need those equations later to help you find the unknown numbers before & after on keystream. Work on what you do know first.

Comment: @unseen_rider Okay so I can create the following 3 equations $0=C_0*2+C_1*1$ & $2=C_0*1+C_1*0$ & $2=C_0*0+C_1*2$

Comment: so C0 = 2 and C1 = 2 from those equations? I don't see how I need 5 equations for that

Comment: Check your working. Remember you are working in $\mod 3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via method described in comments presuming each digit of $Z$ is a digit of $S$ $\mod 3$ I get the following;

$$C_0=2$$
$$C_1=1$$
$$S=22011022011$$